# How to filter array of phrases by search term

Tags: swift, search, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` and I'm filtering a `UICollectionView` by search term like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredRecipes = getRecipes().filter({( recipe : Recipe ) -> Bool in
            return recipe.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })

        if searchText == "" || searchText == " " {
            filteredRecipes = getRecipes()
        }

    }
```

Each `Recipe` has a few properties and one of them by which I want to filter is `name`, that is made up of a couple of words like "Red Velvet Cake". Right now, the function would return this recipe if I searched for anything from:

- red
- r
- lvet
- ed velvet

How do I make it so that it filters the recipes based on the **start** of each of the words in the `name`. So it would only return the recipe if I searched for:

- red
- velvet
- cake
- velvet cake

And also so that it returns all recipes if the search terms is nothing, or just empty spaces?

I have looked here for answers and I can only find solutions similar to my existing one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of **`filter(_:)`**, **`contains(where:)`** and **`hasPrefix(_:)`** like so,

```
filteredRecipes = getRecipes().filter({
    let components = $0.name.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return components.contains(where: {
        $0.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased())
    })
})
```

Comment: That makes sense, I am getting an `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type 'Recipe'` error though.

Comment: @sinio Updated that. Check now. I actually took a String example earlier. That was a confusion.

Comment: Ah one more thing. If I put a space after the word, nothing is returned (probably because the phrase is split by empty spaces). Can it be made so that I can search for two words together (or more)?

Comment: Yes, they're split into separate words, so searching for any word in that phrase returns the right items. But, if I do something like "word " or "word otherword", it returns nothing due to that space inside.

Comment: @sinio When "word otherword" this is the case, this will automatically separate into 2 elements in the array.

Comment: So, it's not possible for the user to search for something like "velvet cake" and get results? Right now only "velvet" or "cake" would work.

Comment: @sinio For that you can try using contains directly like you did earlier in the question.

Comment: @sinio What you are expecting is meaningless. You want to get result for "velvet" or "cake" or "velvet cake" but not for "velvet ca"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enumerateSubstrings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416774-enumeratesubstrings) method and compare each word of `recipe.name` with `searchText`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    guard !searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
        filteredRecipes = getRecipes()
        return
    }
    filteredRecipes = getRecipes().filter({
        var result = false
        $0.name.enumerateSubstrings(in: $0.name.startIndex..<$0.name.endIndex, options: [.byWords], { (word, _, _, _) in
            if let word = word, word.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchText) == .orderedSame {
                result = true
            }
        })
        return result
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the whitespace part of your answer and it worked :)